# Two extension methods with same name

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have the following two extension methods (the body of the methods is not particularly important for my question, but including the code anyway)

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        return (source.ContainsKey(key) ? source[key] : defaultValue);
    }
}

public static class WebExtensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this HttpContext context, string name, T defaultValue)
    {
        object value = context.Request.Form[name] ?? context.Request.QueryString[name];
        if (value == null) return defaultValue;
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

These two methods share the same name but they extend two very different types. I would expect the following code to be simple and the compiler to be able to pick the appropriate extension method:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "foo" },
    { 2, "bar" }
};
var result = myDict.GetValue(5, "baz");
```

However, for some unknown reason, Visual Studio refuses to compile my code with the following compile-time error: "The type 'System.Web.HttpContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web'" . This error tells me that the compiler selected the GetValue extension method in the WebExtensions class instead of the one in the DictionaryExtension class.

I was able to get around the problem with the following:

```
var result = DictionaryExtensions.GetValue(myDict, 5, "baz");
```

but I'm trying to understand why the compiler was confused in the first place. Does anybody know why?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/gNPuvD

Comment: Are both `DictionaryExtensions` and `WebExtensions` defined in the same assembly? Or different assemblies? It sounds like your project just needs a reference to System.Web.dll in order to compile.

Comment: @danludwig They are in same assembly. I have an assembly where I have grouped all extension methods. However, it's a different assembly than where they are being invoked from.

Comment: Your error suggests you haven't referenced an assembly that it needs to define `HttpContext`, not that it can't infer which method you want.

Comment: @Selman22 because the `System.Web` namespace is already include in the fiddle.

Comment: Why was my question down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do what the compiler says and add a reference to System.Web.dll. Then it should compile.

Your external assembly where these extension method classes exist take a dependency on System.Web.dll. The compiler should be able to figure out the overload, but in order to do so, it needs to reference the assembly where `HttpContext` exists, which is in System.Web.dll.

On the other hand if you don't want your project that consumes the extension method assembly to take a dependency on System.Web.dll, then you need to define those 2 extension method classes in separate assemblies.

[@Steve Danner has a good solution too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27724851/304832): put the two extension method classes into different namespaces in the same assembly, and omit the using statement for the namespace that contains the `WebExtensions` class.

I run into this occasionally with things like System.Runtime.Serialization, System.ServiceModel.Activation, etc. It can happen when you have a dependency that is twice-removed. In other words your root project depends on an assembly which depends on a type another third assembly.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. Although it's weird to add a reference to System.Web when I don't need it.

Comment: If you don't want the dependency on System.Web.dll, then define the extension methods that use `HttpContext` in a separate assembly from the one that contains the `DictionaryExtensions` class.

Comment: ...or, as I mentioned in my question, simply use the var result = DictionaryExtension.GetValue() syntax.

Comment: Yes that works because the compiler doesn't have to resolve the overload (two extension methods with same name). When you write it as a static method, the compiler doesn't have to resolve the extension method overload.

Comment: ok, I added reference to System.Web as you suggested and indeed the error is gone and my code compiles. I will stick with the "DictionaryExtension.GetValue" syntax because I don't really want the additional reference but you have helped me understand why the compiler was confused. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, one detail I forgot to mention: pressing F12 in Visual Studio while cursor is over the GetValue method takes me to appropriate extension method which means that Visual Studio is able to correctly resolve without the reference to System.Web. Why is it that VS.NET can resolve while I edit my code but it can't resolve when compiling???

Comment: Probably because VS loaded System.Web.dll. It might even be in the GAC on your development machine.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to break your 2 Extension classes out into separate namespaces and **do not** add a `using` statement where the `WebExtensions` class resides in your consuming code.  That way the compiler won't try and resolve `GetValue` to `WebExtensions`.

Comment: That's much better idea than two assemblies. The point of all this is that the compiler can't run overload resolution without you referencing the assembly. This takes out the overload resolution the same way using the standard method syntax does.